# Add JavaScript and css to page with nodes only if there is no tag in any of the nodes

Tags: 7, javascript

I wrote a module that adds javascript and css to a page with nodes of type 'rower', now I need to add javascript and css to the page only if there is no tag with id == 1503 in any of the nodes. I tried to do it myself but it does not work because the variable $containsOutletTag == TRUE only at last node. Can you please tell me how I can do this? Here's what I have for now:

```
<?php
function countdown_preprocess_node(&$vars)
{
  if ($vars['type'] === 'rower') {
    $containsOutletTag = false;

    foreach ($vars['field_product_tags']['und'] as $tag) {
      if ($tag['tid'] == 1503) {
        $containsOutletTag = true;
      }
    }

    if (!$containsOutletTag) {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'countdown') . '/src/countdown.css');
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'countdown') . '/src/countdown.js');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set your JS to ignore the node if it has that value?

Comment: To add to what @Jaypan said, you should use the Drupal settings mechanism to pass values such as IDs from PHP to JavaScript, so as to keep your JS nice and clean.

Comment: Remove `$containsOutletTag = true;` and place the `drupal_add_...` code there.

Comment: This does not work for me, because I need to add javascript, only if neither node has no tag value $tag['tid'] == 1503

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have use hook_preprocess_node as it gets fired on each node separately, so if only one of the node doesn't have that specific tag the css and javascript will be added to the page unless other nodes have, so rather than hook_preprocess_node use hook_preprocess_page and there you can find an array of nodes (use dsm function with devel module enabled to see variable structure) and you can iterate over that array and check for condition

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried hook_preprocess_page, but it does'nt work for me